# Build a tree structure (for a table of contents) from an array in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I have an array of strings that came from html tags....

```
String[] Headers = {"H1", "H1", "H2", "H3", "H3", "H2", "H2", "H3", "H4", "H2", "H2", "H2", "H1", "H2", "H2", "H3", "H4", "H4", "H2" };
```

That I need turned into a tree structure.  Where any Hn is the child of the most recent Hn-1

```
ROOT
    H1
    H1
    ...H2
    ......H3
    ......H3
    ...H2
    ...H2
    ......H3
    .........H4
    ...H2
    ...H2
    ...H2
    H1
    ...H2
    ...H2
    ......H3
    .........H4
    .........H4
    ...H2
```

This feels like something that should be done with recursion and something that when I seen a solution I'm going to kick myself for not thinking of it sooner.  Anyone got a solution for me?

***Update***:

So I had tried several variations of recursion with absolute no luck.  As it turns out I was making this problem way harder than it had to be.

Because of a test case that came up,

String[] Headers = {"H1", "H1", "H3", "H3", "H5", "H4", "H4", "H4"};

I made a very slight tweak of bcorso's answer, here is what I ended up with:

```
private void addChildren(TocItem root, Elements headers) {
    if(headers == null || headers.size() == 0) return;

    Map<Integer, TocItem> mostRecent = new HashMap<Integer, TocItem>(headers.size());

    int startLevel = getTagLevel(headers.get(0)) - 1;
    mostRecent.put(startLevel, root);

    for(int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) {
        Element htag = headers.get(i);
        int level = getTagLevel(htag);
        TocItem next = new TocItem(htag, level);

        int offset = 1;
        TocItem parent =  mostRecent.get(level - offset);
        while(parent == null && offset < level) {
            offset++;
            parent = mostRecent.get(level - offset);
        }
        if(parent != null) {
            parent.addChild(next);
        }
        mostRecent.put(level, next);
    } 
}
```

Comment: where did you get this question from ?

Comment: A stack and a for loop will be enough to build the tree. Could you give it a go now?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev it comes from the project I'm working on...I'm passing in a whole bunch of html that I'm parsing with Jsoup and I need to turn all the headers into a table of contents.  The problems I'm having are when going from an h4 back to an h2 or h1 for instance.

Comment: @kasdega My answer notwithstanding, you should probably be using a proper DOM library instead of a solution created from scratch

Comment: @kasdega I've added an answer that is quite simple to follow if you would like to take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here is a working example on Ideone](https://ideone.com/D6QYr2). The code is also below:

```
public static class Node{
    int level;
    List<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node>();
    Node(int level){ this.level = level;}
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception{
    String[] h = {"H1", "H1", "H2", "H3", "H3", "H5", "H2", "H2", "H3", "H4",
                  "H2", "H2", "H2", "H1", "H2", "H2", "H3","H4", "H4", "H2"};
                        
    Node[] mostRecent = new Node[6];                      // 5 headers + 1 root tag.
    mostRecent[0] = new Node(0);                          // root tag (level = 0)

    for(int i = 0; i < h.length; i++){
        int level = Integer.parseInt(""+h[i].charAt(1));  // get tag's "level"
        Node n = new Node(level);                         // create Node for tag
        mostRecent[level] = n;                            // update most recent tag
              
        int pLevel = level - 1;                          
        while(mostRecent[pLevel] == null) --pLevel;       // find nearest parent
        mostRecent[pLevel].children.add(n);               // append tag Node to parent
        
        for(int j = 1; j < level; j++)                    // print tag with indention
            System.out.print("\t");
        System.out.println(h[i]);
    } 
}
```

---

### Code Explaination:

It runs in `O(n)` time by simply walking though the list of headers `h` in a for-loop, and keeping track of the most recent `H1`, `H2`, `H3`, and `H4`, in an array, `Node[]`.

The array is used to retrieved the most recent node of tag `Hi` by referencing it's level using the corresponding integer. For instance, the node with the most recent "H1" tag is retrieved using `mostRecent[1]` (note, element `0` is the used as the root of the whole document).

**Note:** If you need a dedicated function to print the tree [see this Ideone](https://ideone.com/BypIe3).

Comment: this is indeed a great answer...thank you for taking the time to write this up.

Comment: Check out my update - I tweaked what you had just slightly to work for the case...H3 H3 H5 H4 h4  (no parent h4)

Comment: @kasdega can you update the example in your question to include the above case? So in this case what will H5 parent be if there are no previous H4's?

Comment: It would move down the line to the most recent h3, then h2, then h1 until it either finds one and uses that, or doesn't find one in which case it just add it to the mostRecent.

Comment: Okay, I also added this to my answer. You should probably update your original question because this extends your original requirement: "Hn is the child of the most recent Hn-1".

Comment: you're right its different than the original question but I think its ok.  You're solution worked great.

Answer (score 4):

Here ya go:

```
class Example
{
    static class Node
    {
        final String name;
        final int indent;
        Collection<Node> children = new LinkedList<> ();

        Node (final String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.indent = Integer.valueOf (name.substring (1));
        }
        Collection<Node> getChildren ()
        {
            return Collections.unmodifiableCollection (this.children);
        }
        void addChild (final Node child)
        {
            this.children.add (child);
        }
        @Override
        public String toString ()
        {
            final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ();
            for (int i = 0; i < this.indent; i++)
                sb.append ("   ");
            sb.append (this.name).append ('\n');
            for (final Node node : this.children)
                sb.append (node.toString ());
            return sb.toString ();
        }
    }

    List<Node> contents = new LinkedList<> ();
    ArrayList<Node> stack = new ArrayList<> ();

    public void add (final String[] headers)
    {
        for (final String h : headers)
        {
            final int n = Integer.valueOf (h.substring (1));
            final Node node = new Node (h);

            while (this.stack.size () > n - 1)
                this.stack.remove (this.stack.size () - 1);

            if (n == 1)
            {
                this.contents.add (node);
                this.stack.add (node);
            }
            else
            {
                this.stack.get (n - 2).addChild (node);

                if (this.stack.size () < n)
                {
                    assert (this.stack.size () == n - 1);
                    this.stack.add (node);
                }
            }
        }
        this.stack.clear ();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ()
    {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ();
        for (final Node node : this.contents)
            sb.append (node.toString ());
        return sb.toString ();
    }
}
```

To use:

```
    final Example ex = new Example ();
    ex.add (new String[] {"H1", "H1", "H2", "H3", "H3", "H2", "H2", "H3", "H4", "H2", "H2",
            "H2", "H1", "H2", "H2", "H3", "H4", "H4", "H2"});
    System.out.println (ex);
```

Comment: Please fix code - Illegal modifier for the class Example; only public, abstract & final are permitted

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev Derp, my bad. Remove the 'static' modifier. It has that because I wrote it as a nested class

Comment: Your answer works, upvoted. I have never used java this way - nodes and all. My programs are mostly basic. Can you please give me a summary of how your code works ? I'd really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev Sure. Each node represents one of the "H#" strings. As the array is parsed, two collections are maintained. 'contents' contains all base nodes ("H1"s), while 'stack' contains the last H1, H2, H3, etc. When a node is found of indent x (H3 : x=3), nodes are removed from the stack which are greater than H2. Then the new node is added to the node at the end of the stack as a child, and also becomes the new top of the stack, then the process repeats. The printing is pretty straight-forward

Comment: Aside from the fact that this doesn't look like any java I've ever come across - it none the less does answer my question.  Thank you.